# SFDX retrieve source in Manifest from org

Tags: package, cli, manifest

I installed the sf extension for vscode and got everything to run with the default package.xml.
I exported the whole package from my org with the help of [Package builder](https://packagebuilder.herokuapp.com/)
and inserted it to the package.xml in the manifest folder. Now retrieve source from org exits with this error:

```
> Starting SFDX: Retrieve Source from Org
> 
> 15:10:34.965 sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest
> p:\sf_code\developer\manifest\package.xml ERROR running
> force:source:retrieve:  EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
> 15:12:45.841 sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest
> p:\sf_code\developer\manifest\package.xml ended with exit code 1
```

I get the same error when entering the command to the sfcli outside vscode

Comment: Do you have a default org setup?  Otherwise you might need to use the `-u MyConnectedOrg` parameter in the `force:source:retrieve` command

Comment: Yes I am connected to my sandbox and I retrieved some data but not everything

Comment: Probably, it's possible to run it only from the project folder.
sfdx:source:retrieve --manifest ./manifest/package.xml

Comment: What do you mean? Am I not running it from the project folder?
>sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest p:\sf_code\developer\manifest\package.xml

Comment: I also navigated to the project folder and sfdx force:source:retrieve --manifest manifest\package.xml. Got the same error

Comment: I narrowed it down to Dashboards and Reports. Everything works when i comment out these types.Is there a known problem?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue discussed here - https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/issues/680

Retrieving any metadata with a folder structure seems to have this problem. Remove them from package.xml and things should work fine.

Use ANT to retrieve the hierarchical metadata and add it to the project folder.